# apache web server | mpm = event | configuration is unable to apply after restart of web server

Tags: apache

I have to change the event mpm default configuration to address the error (scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase,ServerLimit) however I am not able to see any impact after made changes in httpd.conf file.

While I have check the httpd process it showing 3 servers are running with 25 thread. Please find detail below

```
[q@mohitm ~]$ ps -ef|grep httpd
root      67465      1  0 22:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
tomcat    67467  67465  0 22:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
tomcat    67468  67465  0 22:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
tomcat    67470  67465  0 22:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
sdlansi   68271  65078  0 22:21 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto httpd
[q@mohitm ~]$ ps -eLo pid,lwp,nlwp,ruser,pcpu,stime,etime,args|grep  67467
 67467  67467   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67471   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67472   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67479   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67480   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67481   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67482   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67483   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67484   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67485   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67486   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67487   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67489   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67491   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67493   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67496   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67498   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67500   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67502   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67504   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67506   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67508   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67510   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67512   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67514   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67516   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 67467  67518   27 tomcat    0.0 22:00       22:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
 68283  68283    1 sdlansi   0.0 22:22       00:00 grep --color=auto 67467
```

> Please help me how I can check my configuration is applied or not.
>   Above artifacts are showing that only 3 servers are run with 25
>   ThreadsPerChild

in httpd.conf I have added below configuration to tune even mpm - After done restart my apache server to apply

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
            StartServers              6         #default 3
            ServerLimit               512       #default 16
            ThreadsPerChild           25        #25
            MaxRequestWorkers      12800        #default 400(16x25)
            AsyncWorkerFactor         2
            MinSpareThreads           64        # MaxRequestWorkers / 4
            MaxSpareThreads          256        #64 MinSpareThreads * 3
            MaxConnectionsPerChild     0
</IfModule>
```

apache server detail is

```
[root@mohitm ~]# apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.4 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr 16 2014 17:28:21
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:11
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.0, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Compiled using: APR 1.5.0, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"
```

Machine : 8 core 16 GB

Answer (score 1):

You can use module called check_httpd_limits to check which event type your apache. It will show the configured parameters and their respective values which are being used by apache. For further details go through following link.

https://github.com/jsmoriss/check-httpd-limits

Comment: Thanks Karan, This script read from httpd.conf file. Is there any tool/command which help me to check whether my configuration applied or not ?

Answer (score 0):

> Solved! my observation was right.

Now its showing all configured Workers and StartServers

[image]